# MagicZoom loads all large images not only the default one

Tags: zooming, magiczoomplus, magiczoom

MagicZoom lib claims in the documentation that only the large image for the default image will be initially downloaded and the rest of the large images for each thumbnail will be downloaded after the page is loaded.

However, when I inspect the network traffic (using Firebug Net tab) I can clearly see that all large images are downloaded before the 'full page load' event is triggered.

Is this a bug in the magiczoom lib or is there a a work around this problem?

I reviewed their doc for pre-load and initialization but it doesn't give me want I want (i.e. download only the first large image so the zoom in capability is there right away, and the rest on demand or after full page load):

http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/integration/#preload

Answer (score 0):

Magic Zoom loads only the first large image by default, assuming you are following the documentation here:

http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/integration/#multiple

```
<a href="1big.jpg" class="MagicZoom" id="bike"><img src="1small.jpg"></a>
<a href="1big.jpg" rel="zoom-id:bike" rev="1small.jpg"><img src="1tiny.jpg"/></a>
<a href="2big.jpg" rel="zoom-id:bike" rev="2small.jpg"><img src="2tiny.jpg"/></a>
<a href="3big.jpg" rel="zoom-id:bike" rev="3small.jpg"><img src="3tiny.jpg"/></a>
```

If other large images are loading on page load, then something else on your page is causing them to download. Please post the URL of your page so that the cause can be identified.

Comment: You can see it happening on this page: http://www.clearlycontacts.co.nz/joseph-marc-4010?rsView=true

Comment: Magic Toolbox, do you have any suggestions?